# has "container" word a meaning in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to work on some procedures in oracle 11. On Oracle SQL Developer I was writing some code and noted that the word CONTAINER, I'd like to use as name of a column, has written in blue like others keywords, like VARCHAR, TYPE, TABLE, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevertheless it is used by the CDB/PDB features but it is not considered a reserved word:

```
  1* select keyword, reserved from v$reserved_words where keyword = 'CONTAINER'
SQL> /

KEYWORD          RESERVED
-------------------- ----------
CONTAINER        N

SQL>
```

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Keywords.html#GUID-82EA000B-5661-41EB-AAF7-6BDDB4AB58EE) says:

> Oracle SQL keywords are not reserved. However, Oracle uses them
>   internally in specific ways. Therefore, if you use these words as
>   names for objects and object parts, then your SQL statements may be
>   more difficult to read and may lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: "may lead to unpredictable results" from oracle docs is the sentence I like to read to decide is bad use this name

Comment: Rather than continue to  struggle with trying to use object names that are known to be problematic, why not just use a different name?  I have a personal naming standard that avoids this problem every time, without even having to consider if a name might be reserved or a key word. Why are you so wedded to that one name?

Comment: I agree with you... anyway I'm evolving a system already created in which those names are already mapped as the name of some json fields received by java application from a rest service. Container is just a new field received, I'm not able to create a standard or convention now because I should rename in oracle all names created by someone else before me...

Answer (score 1):

No problem:

```
SQL> select * From v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> create table test (container number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

I guess that SQL Developer *marked* it because of 12c+ database versions as there are "**container**" and "pluggable" databases, but - no problem in 12c either (tried it, works).